# How to pass variable while filtering Mongodb INPUT in Kettle

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle

How to pass the current date while filtering Mongodb INPUT?

Current date is Pentaho system date

query in mongo db input

```
{ created_at : { $gte : { $date : "2014-12-31T00:00:00.000Z" } } }
```

Instead of `2014-12-31T00:00:00.000Z` -> today's date in same format `2014-12-31T00:00:00.000Z` in a variable like `$TODAY-DATE`

I need to replace the value with todays date via variable

Someting like below:

```
{ created_at : { $gte : { $date : "$TODAY-DATE" } } }
```

Comment: Where would this variable be coming from? What language are you using? What stop you from using this as a variable in the language?

Comment: The value of the variable will be coming from system info step which gives system date(fixed). I will have this variable available under environment variable while runing the transformation .I am using PDI kettle

Comment: Well I don't know much about that tech but I have tagged it correctly now, we will see if someone does know the answer

Comment: Hi! You need to replace the date-value in your input-step with a variable coming from PDI?
What about a job where you define the variable in a transformation before your input-transformation?

Comment: Let me now if you want further information about doing this with a Job ...

Comment: Seb,Thanks for the reply .I have done that by creating a job and using the value in variable however I want to know why cant the incoming stream from system info step(having fixed system date) be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to try the following:

1. Within the job that calls the transformation, create a variable that meets the format expectations. You could use the `JavaScript` step to evaluate and store the variable. Example for a short script that stores a value in a variable:

   ```
   // do some alterations to 'modifiedDate',
   // then store the variable in the memory:
   parent_job.setVariable("Extraction.MongoDB.Date", modifiedDate);
   ```
2. Pass the variable as a parameter onto the transformation (Edit Job Entry ==> Parameters tab);
3. Call the variable using the following convention: `${Extraction.MongoDB.Date}` within the relevant MongoDB Input step fields;

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax to pass variable is if `TODAY-DATE` is a variable

```
{ created_at : { $gte : ${TODAY-DATE} } }
```